Is there a way to load a memory-only pointer type
I'm trying to write a solution to a problem I found online using Mojo. The problem is a graph theory related so I wanted to implement the data structure by hand to get more familiar with the language.
from memory import Pointer
from collections import List

struct NodeEdge:
    var node1P: Pointer[Node] 
    var node2P: Pointer[Node]
    var edgeWeight: UInt16 

    fn __init__(inout self, inout node1: Node, inout node2: Node, weight: UInt16) -> NoneType:
        self.node1P = Pointer[Node].address_of(node1)
        self.node2P = Pointer[Node].address_of(node2)
        self.edgeWeight = weight
        node1.addEdge(self)
        node2.addEdge(self)

    fn __copyinit__(inout self, node1: NodeEdge) -> NoneType:
        self.node1P = node1.node1P
        self.node2P = node1.node2P
        self.edgeWeight = node1.edgeWeight

    fn __moveinit__(inout self, owned node1: NodeEdge) -> NoneType:
        self.node1P = node1.node1P
        self.node2P = node1.node2P
        self.edgeWeight = node1.edgeWeight


struct Node:
    var nodeType: String
    var nodeData: List[UInt16]
    var nodeEdges: List[NodeEdge]

    fn __init__(inout self) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeType = ''
        self.nodeData = List[UInt16]()
        self.nodeEdges = List[NodeEdge]()
        

    fn __init__(inout self, ntype: String, data: List[UInt16], edges: List[NodeEdge]) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeType = ntype
        self.nodeData = data
        self.nodeEdges = edges

    fn addEdge(inout self, edge: NodeEdge) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeEdges.append(edge)

    fn setNodeType(inout self, ntype: String) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeType = ntype

    fn setNodeData(inout self, data: List[UInt16]) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeData = data

    fn setNodeEdgeData(inout self, data: List[NodeEdge]) -> NoneType:
        self.nodeEdges = data

    fn printNode(inout self) -> String:
        var res: String
        res = self.nodeType + "\n"
        for i in range(self.nodeData.size):
            res.__iadd__(self.nodeData[i])
            res.__iadd__(" ")
        res.__iadd__("\n")

        for i in range(self.nodeEdges.size):
            res.__iadd__(self.nodeEdges[i].edgeWeight)
            res.__iadd__(" ")
        res.__iadd__("\n")
        return res

    fn printFirstEdgeNode(inout self) -> String:
        var res: String
        var firstNodeEdge = self.nodeEdges[0]
        var pSelf = Pointer[Node].address_of(self)
        if (pSelf.__eq__(firstNodeEdge.node1P)):
            #ERROR Occurrs here 
            var nodeToPrint = firstNodeEdge.node2P.load()
        else: 
            #print other node
            pass
        return ''




fn main():
    var node1 = Node()
    var ndata1: List[UInt16]
    
    var node2 = Node()
    var ndata2: List[UInt16]

    ndata1 = List[UInt16](17)
    ndata2 = List[UInt16](12,2)
    node1.setNodeType("Sum")
    node2.setNodeType("Path")
    node1.setNodeData(ndata1)
    node2.setNodeData(ndata2)

    createEdges(node1, node2)
    print(node1.printFirstEdgeNode())


fn createEdges(inout node1: Node, inout node2: Node) -> NoneType:
    var edge = NodeEdge(node1, node2, 5)

I want the function printFirstEdgeNode to be able to look at its list of edge nodes and select the first one and print that node using the printNode function. The problem I'm encountering is in trying to load the pointer from the list of edges. Since each edge has a link to the nodes its connecting, I figure if I was able to load the Node object from that pointer then call the print node function on that object I could get the result I want, but I'm thinking that since it's a memory-only struct I'm not going to be able to do it like this. Is there a similar way to accomplish this?

